# Using OpenSSL from Ports - FreeBSD

Tags: openssl, freebsd

I've installed open/security package using pkg install open/security.
My base OpenSSL version is 0.9.8 and the one I've installed on port (/usr/local/bin/ssl) is 1.0.2.

I've added DEFAULT_VERSIONS+= ssl=openssl to my /etc/make.conf file. Do I need to do anything else to make sure that my changes are reflected?

I keep reading that I need to re-build my files, I don't know how though. I'm new to FreeBSD. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about FreeBSD and other Unix operating systems are to be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

An option would be "to upgrade all the outdated ports installed on the system" (see [4.5.3.3. Upgrading Ports Using Portupgrade](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html))

> portupgrade -a

In particular "to rebuild all packages associated with OpenSSL". (see [Keep OpenSSL updated on FreeBSD](https://gist.github.com/dmckeone/e18e57f727d2b13ccc08d8d4b17c68ea))

> portupgrade -Rrf security/openssl

This may take a long time to complete. Do not run this in production. Test and learn the procedure with a small installation first.

In production best practice is to (1) build the packages with [Poudriere](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-poudriere.html) in a dedicated box (2) test it and then (3) use the binaries to update production boxes.

It might be useful to read the whole chapter [4. Installing Applications: Packages and Ports](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports.html) first. Backup data and configuration before the update. It is useful to keep the configuration in some system management framework.

Do not forget to review /usr/ports/UPDATING !

See [Upgrade OpenSSL 1.0.2 > 1.1.1](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/upgrade-openssl-1-0-2-1-1-1.67560/)